# macro to attach a worksheet with vba code and have the worksheet edited to upload to a shared excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've used this for many of my projects that I have been creating for work. I have learned a lot but I am hitting a wall.

As my staff uses the save and send as attachment manually  notify me and the other department, I want to have to macro buttons installed. If I install the macro buttons to the worksheet it will need to be emailed as a macro-enabled worksheet correct?

Also, everything appears to work in this sub except for the Attachments part...I would like it to continue to be generic so anyone can upload using the 2nd VBA code

## 1

```
    Sub SendReferral()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutlookMail
        .To = "_" & Range("b2").Value & "Services@gmail.com"
        .CC = "myself"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Referral for " & Range("d2").Value & " - " & Range("f2").Value
        .Body = "Hello, please follow up with the member within 2 business days, thank you."
        .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

I have been trying to modify this one but presently cannot get past the FilePath line so I cannot check if the rest of the Sub will work.

## 2

```
    Sub UploadReferral()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
    FilePath = "\\profiler\docs$\Manager Docs\Global Referrals -                 Testing.xlsx"
        If FileAlreadyOpen(FilePath) = True Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:0:30"), "TransferData"
            Worksheets("Flat File").CommandButton1.Enabled = False
            Worksheets("Flat File").CommandButton1.Caption = "Saving... Please wait"
        Else:
            Workbooks.Open (FilePath)
            With Workbooks("Global Referrals.xlsx").Worksheets("Referrals")
            NewRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Workbooks("ReferralForm1.xlsm").Activate
            LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For I = 2 To LastRow
                For J = 1 To 14
                    .Cells(NewRow, J) = Cells(I, J)
                Next J
                .Cells(NewRow, 15) = Environ("UserName")
                NewRow = NewRow + 1
            Next I
            End With
            Worksheets("ReferralForm1").CommandButton1.Enabled = True
            Worksheets("ReferralForm1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Transfer Data"
            Workbooks("Global referrals.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
            MsgBox "Global Referrals updated"
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Taking a quick look at this it appears that you are trying to call either a sub or function which does not exist `If FileAlreadyOpen(FilePath) = True Then`

Do you have code somewhere else for the `FileAlreadyOpen` call?

Comment: #EdHunter - No, this is all the code I have as of now. I have tried messing with it and removing and renaming but I run into the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

that should fix the attachment part

**1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendReferral()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object


    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutlookMail
        .To = "Services@gmail.com " & Range("b2").Value & " Services@gmail.com"
        .CC = "Services@gmail.com "
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Referral for " & Range("d2").Value & " - " & Range("f2").Value
        .Body = "Hello, please follow up with the member within 2 business days, thank you."
         ActiveWorkbook.Save
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        '.Display '<<<---- use it for editing 
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

**2**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UploadReferral()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NewRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer

    FilePath = "\\profiler\docs$\Manager Docs\Global Referrals\Testing.xlsx"

    If FileAlreadyOpen(FilePath) = True Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:0:30"), "TransferData"
        Worksheets("Flat File").CommandButton1.Enabled = False
        Worksheets("Flat File").CommandButton1.Caption = "Saving... Please wait"
    Else:
        Workbooks.Open (FilePath)
        With Workbooks("Global Referrals.xlsx").Worksheets("Referrals")
        NewRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Workbooks("ReferralForm1.xlsm").Activate
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For I = 2 To LastRow
                For J = 1 To 14
                    .Cells(NewRow, J) = Cells(I, J)
                Next J
                .Cells(NewRow, 15) = Environ("UserName")
                NewRow = NewRow + 1
            Next I
        End With
        Worksheets("ReferralForm1").CommandButton1.Enabled = True
        Worksheets("ReferralForm1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Transfer Data"
        Workbooks("Global referrals.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
            MsgBox "Global Referrals updated"
    End If
End Sub

Function FileAlreadyOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim iFilenum As Long
    Dim iErr As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    iFilenum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
    Close iFilenum
    iErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case iErr
    Case 0:    FileAlreadyOpen = False
    Case 70:   FileAlreadyOpen = True
    Case Else: Error iErr
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Unless .Display does something other than just display the email to allow you to make edits prior to it being sent then there is no need to use .Display if you are using .Send

Comment: @Omar I did test it. It doesn't automatically send but it does pop up the screen to have it emailed and that is successful. It does give an error about what I'm assuming is the automated .Send part. On #2 o haven't received feedback yet so I am still stuck on the FilePath part

Comment: Remove the `.Display ` & change the - `'.Send`   To  `.Send`  that should fix the automate the send with out the pop up. on #2 if you don't have access to `\\profiler\` then you will get Error

Comment: @Omar. I'll go ahead and remove display and leave the send. Could it be a macro security with work to run to the profiler file? I do have access but I ran into the same problem at home when testing it on a file in a separate drive